# Couldn't call a function in mysql trigger. Error is: Undeclared variable

Tags: mysql, function, triggers

I am having a mysql user defined function called SPLIT_STRING in my database as

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR`(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '')
```

to split the value according to the position, and i am using trigger to update the status where i need a temp variable to store the data with the help of function `SPLIT_STR` as

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_tbl1_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl1`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE cab_meter_new VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE cab_cost_new VARCHAR(10);

SET @cab_meter_new = SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 1); 
select SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 1) INTO @cab_meter_new,SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 2) INTO @cab_meter_old; //Throws error
----
---
--
END //
delimiter ;
```

Where if i call a function in trigger it throws an error as

```
#1327 - Undeclared variable: SPLIT_STR
```

Is this right way to call a function to set variable, Can we able to call a function in trigger, I am using Mysql version 5.1.66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry the problem is the syntax of select into

```
select SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 1) INTO @cab_meter_new,SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 2) INTO @cab_meter_old; // Incorrect - and shows SPLIT_STR is not defined(Thinks as variable)

select SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 1),SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 2)  INTO @cab_meter_new, @cab_meter_old; //Correct syntax to store multiple
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SET @cab_meter_new := SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 1); //Throwing error here
```

or you can::

```
Select SPLIT_STR(NEW.gps_rs232, '|', 1) INTO @cab_meter_new;
```

Comment: I tried that too and second one i already mentioned in question itself but no use..